# Can’t use variable for angularfire2 list name in firebase(ionic)

Tags: javascript, typescript, firebase, ionic-framework, angularfire2

I can’t use a variable to hold the name of my list on firebase.

After I push some data the variable becomes undefined in firebase.

`$this.UserID` is meant to hold the UID but it can't be read.

My code:

```js
private referenceListRef;
UserID: string;

constructor(private http: Http, 
            private db: AngularFireDatabase,
            private ofAuth: AngularFireAuth,
            public storage: Storage
) {
    this.ofAuth.authState.take(1).subscribe(data => {
        this.UserID = data.uid;
        console.log(`user id : ${this.UserID}`);
    })
    this.referenceListRef =  this.db.list(`${this.UserID}`);
 
}
```

Comment: im sorry, i was kinda confused as what to type, or to ask so perhaps the question was a bit confusing. and again english isn't my main language. so thank you so much for editing that post. now that looks like a proper question!

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `referenceListRef` inside `subscribe()`, because you don't have `this.UserID` before `this.ofAuth.authState` Observable's completes.

```
private referenceListRef;
UserID: string;

constructor(private http: Http, 
            private db: AngularFireDatabase,
            private ofAuth: AngularFireAuth,
            public storage: Storage
) {
    this.ofAuth.authState.take(1).subscribe(data => {
        this.UserID = data.uid;
        console.log(`user id : ${this.UserID}`);
        this.referenceListRef =  this.db.list(`${this.UserID}`); // <-- This code
    })
}
```

Comment: thanks! i tried it  but unfortunately now i get this error "cannot read property snapshotchanges of undefined"

Comment: wait, turns out if i click close after the error, which will send me back to the login page and i re-login, it works. but somehow if i restart the app the errorwill come out again. so i have to close the error message and re login. but hey it worked! thanks!